# Retrieving Model MetaData from within a validation attribute

Tags: c#, .net, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

Using MVC4 I need to retrieve the current `ModelMetadata` from within a custom `ValidationAttribute`. The reason for this is that the Validation Attribute needs to be aware of which other attributes are attached to the specific property in which is being validated.

In specific it much check whether the property has an `UppercaseAttribute` attached to it; if this is the case then it will perform a different path of logic. If it is possible to grab the `ModelMetadata` from within the `ValidationAttribute`, I will use the following code to check for it:

```
ModelMetadata.ContainerType
    .GetProperty(ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName)
    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(UppercaseAttribute), true)
```

Firstly, is it possible to retrieve the `ModelMetadata` from within a custom `ValidationAttribute`.

Secondly, is the above code the best practice for checking whether a property has a specific attribute attached to it.

Comment: Do you need this validation attribute for a specific Model only? If that's the case, can you post your Model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    var model = validationContext.ObjectInstance;

    var displayName = validationContext.DisplayName;
    var propertyName = model.GetType().GetProperties()
        .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<DisplayAttribute>().Any(a => a.Name == displayName))
        .Select(p => p.Name).FirstOrDefault();
    if (propertyName == null)
        propertyName = displayName;

    var property = model.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    var uppercaseAttribute = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(UppercaseAttribute), false).SingleOrDefault() as UppercaseAttribute;

    if (uppercaseAttribute != null)
    {
        // some code...
    }

    // return validation result...
}
```

For some reason, validationContext.MemberName is always null, so you have to get the property name based on its display name.

Comment: Brilliant! That is pretty much where I got to except I was stumped on how to get property name due to validationContext.MemberName being null. I guess if the Display Name is null then it will default to the Property Name?

Comment: Yes, validationContext.DisplayName returns Property Name if there's no Display Name.

The only problem with the code in my answer is that it won't work if two properties have the same Display Name, but that is usually not the case.

Comment: Yes I did notice this, but I cannot think of a scenario where this would happen in my code..

Answer (score 4):

To answer your first question: yes. You can access the `ModelMetadata` object within a `ValidationAttribute` object. The simpliest way to do this is to implement the `System.Web.Mvc.IMetadataAware` interface. The interface has one method called `OnMetadataCreated` that will be called prior to the `IsValid` method on the validation attribute object. This method is used to recieve the current ModelMetadata object. The following code demonstrates the usage:

```
   public class MyCustomValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IMetadataAware
    {
        private readonly object _typeId = new object();
        private ModelMetadata _metadata;

        public MyCustomValidationAttribute()
        {
        }

        public override object TypeId
        {
            get
            {
                return _typeId;
            }
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            //Do something with the meta data
            string propertyName = _metadata.PropertyName;

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata)
        {
            _metadata = metadata;         
        }
    }
```